# SQLite - Check before insert all characters in a varchar

Tags: sql, sqlite, char, database-trigger

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id integer primary key,
    email varchar not null,
    ...
);
```

On insert, I want to check wether the email has this specific format:

```
'a@b.c'
```

Additionally I want to check that `a`, `b` and `c` contain only latin letters (ASCII 65-90) and `a`, `b` can also contain numbers (ASCII 48-57).

I thought of creating a trigger and going through all characters of the varchar. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Why not underscores `_` or dots `.`?

Comment: That's really hard to do with stock sqlite. If you load an extension module that provides regular expression support or have a user defined function that does the validation you can add a check constraint, though.

Comment: Also, no such thing as a `varchar` type. Read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html to see how a column type like that is handled in a table definition.